# c# regex match set of characters in any order only once

Tags: c#, regex

I need to match any combination of characters in set, in any order, but not duplicate characters. The set is "m,s,b,r,e,l,f,t" and for example

```
msb - valid
mbs - valid
m - valid
mmft - not valid (duplicate m)
mxel - not valid (x is not in set)
```

I use this tester
http://regexstorm.net/tester

This is closest but will not capture all order combinations

```
^(?:[m]{1})|(?:[n]{1})$
```

For example nm will not be captured.

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you using the regex inside C# code? I suggest you just grab all the matches with `^[msbrelft]+$`, and then filter out those that contain dupe chars.

Comment: Does "duplicate" mean more than one, or does it mean multiple successive?

Comment: I just test for moment but plan to validate a string so any solution will be welcome.

Comment: No groups, only one letter

Comment: @Wiktor, what you propose will allow duplicate letters

Comment: Do you want only to know if the string is a match of what you are saying?

Comment: @user1734108 Of course `^[msbrelft]+$` will match any number of those chars, but all you need to add is to check if there are any dupes. It is the easies way.

Comment: @dcg yes, those letters are some groups (imported) in my app and should not be duplicate groups. And groups are denoted by those 8 letters only. So I need to validate if string is correct.

Comment: @Wiktor I am not sure I follow you. Check dupes after regex with a loop?

Comment: See the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to know if the string is a match you can do something like:

```
private bool IsMatch(string str) {
    HashSet<char> set = new HashSet<char>("msbrelft"),
                  viewed = new HashSet<char>();

    foreach (var c in str) {
        if (!set.Contains(c)) return false;
        if (viewed.Contains(c)) return false;
        viewed.Add(c);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I accepted this because of simplicity (HashSet). Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If only consecutive repetitions are not allowed (like in `mmft`), use this regex

```
^(?!.*(.)\1)[msbrelft]+$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/11pGQB/1

If any character recurrence is not allowed (like in `mftm`), use this:

```
^(?!.*(.).*\1)[msbrelft]+$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/q1bpMr/1

The key point in the both regexes is the recurrence checking lookbehind:

- In the first case (`^(?!.*(.)\1)`) the match fails if there is a character immediately followed by itself (`(.)\1`).
- In the second case (`^(?!.*(.).*\1)`) the match fails if there is a character that repeats after some other sequence (`(.).*\1`).

Comment: Thank you too, I tested 2'nd and capture groups just fine. However, I must further test for not including in captured group. Seems more easily the first answer, thank you too for effort!

Comment: @Dimitry, thank you again! I included your 2'nd solution in another validation, where I tried to match <[SG xxxx]> and I used ^(.|\n)*(<\\[SG )[m|s|b|r|e|l|f|t]{1,8}(]>)(.|\n)*$. But your solution is great <\[SG (?!.*(.).*\1)[msbrelft]+]>

Comment: @user1734108: You're welcome! BTW, don't forget to escape square brackets when they need to be matched literally, i.e. `<\[SG (?!.*(.).*\1)[msbrelft]+\]>`. Also, the pipe (`|`) should not be used when defining character classes in square brackets since it's treated literally in the brackets. I.e. use `[msbrelft]` instead of `[m|s|b|r|e|l|f|t]` in your case.