# c# regex match a group of characters that not repeates

Tags: c#, regex

Inspired by other question here (I already accepted a non-regex solution)
[c# regex match set of characters in any order only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43498582/c-sharp-regex-match-set-of-characters-in-any-order-only-once)

But this solution from @Dmitry Egorov is by far more elegant and I am still struggling to solve it properly (if it can be solved with one regex)
The closest I get is this one

```
^(.|\n)*<\[SG (?!.*(.).*\2)[msbrelft]+\]>(.|\n)*$
```

The text should match is as follows

```
ID-CFI Location 02h displays sector protection status for the sector selected by the sector address (SA) used in the ID-CFI enter
command. To read the protection status of more than one sector it is necessary to exit the ID ASO and enter the ID ASO using the
new SA. <[SG sbl]>
Page mode read between ID locations other than 02h is supported.
```

I use in C# this check

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(obj.Object_Text, format.Value))
...
...
```

In words, match should be:

```
- if this exists anywhere in text <[SG sbl]> including over \n or \r\n
- letters should be in this group of letters [msbrelft]
- must be minimum one letter, eg. <[SG s]>
- can be up to all from group, eg. <[SG sbl]>
- must be only one letter (no duplicates), eg. <[SG sbsl]> is NOT good
```

I don't want to extract group, just validate all text if contain <[SG xx..]> with previous explained rules.

Now what I already come up and drove me crazy, was

```
^(.|\n)*<\[SG (?!.*(.).*\2)[msbrelft]+\]>(.|\n)*$
```

which don't validate if AFTER my interesting group there are two letters ON THE SAME LINE (no \r\n or \n).

So for example this works (there is a \n or \r\n after group)

```
ID-CFI Location 02h displays sector protection status for the sector selected by the sector address (SA) used in the ID-CFI enter
command. To read the protection status of more than one sector it is necessary to exit the ID ASO and enter the ID ASO using the
new SA. <[SG sbl]>
Page mode read between ID locations other than 02h is supported.
```

and this not (two spaces after my group)

```
ID-CFI Location 02h displays sector protection status for the sector selected by the sector address (SA) used in the ID-CFI enter
command. To read the protection status of more than one sector it is necessary to exit the ID ASO and enter the ID ASO using the
new SA. <[SG sbl]>  Page mode read between ID locations other than 02h is supported.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for valid `<SG ...>` substrings? Like [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3c%5c%5bSG%5cs%2b%28%3f!%5bmsbrelft%5d*%28%5bmsbrelft%5d%29%5bmsbrelft%5d*%5c1%29%5bmsbrelft%5d%2b%5d%3e&i=%3c%5bSG+sbl%5d%3e%0d%0a.%3c%5bSG+sbsl%5d%3e)?

Comment: The best way using regex is to get the regex results.  Then use Distinct method on regex results.  When there are no duplicates the regex results and the Distinct results will match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, if you only want to find one `<SG xxx>` with your rules to validate the string, you don't need to describe the full string in your pattern.

The problem with your pattern is that your negative lookahead can check characters outside of the square brackets delimited substring, to avoid the problem you need to change the dot with a negative character class that excludes the closing square bracket:

```
<\[SG (?![^\]]*([^\]])[^\]]*\1)[msbrelft]+\]>
```

You can also write it like this:

```
<\[SG (?:([msbrelft])(?![^\]]*?\1))+\]>
```

Comment: thank you sir! Perfect! It bother's me from yesterday, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the `(.|\n)*` by `[\S\s]*` seems to work.
\S : anything that's not a whitespace
\s : spaces, tabs, linefeeds, ...

```
^[\S\s]*<\[SG (?!\w*(\w)\w*\1)[beflmrst]+\]>[\S\s]*$
```

Also, the negative lookahead to avoid the duplicates now uses `\w`, instead of `.`.
Since `]` is not a wordcharacter, it won't search beyond it.
\w : word characters.

Or, like Wiktor pointed out, pass `RegexOptions.Singleline` to the regex constructor and the regex can be golfcoded to :

```
^.*<\[SG (?!\w*(\w)\w*\1)[beflmrst]+\]>.*$
```

Anyway, from the other answer I noticed that you really only wanted to search for that SG tag, instead of getting the whole text if it contains the tag.

So in the end, this will do :

```
<\[SG (?!\w*(\w)\w*\1)[beflmrst]+\]>
```

Comment: No need using `[\s\S]` in C#, you can pass `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag to the Regex constructor and `.` will match any character. `.*` is enough then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the hint :)